# How to calculate the variance of this coin flip?

Tags: volatility, probability

I am reading the article “[Shannon’s Demon & How Returns Can Be Created Out of Thin Air](https://www.richmondquant.com/news/2021/9/21/shannons-demon-amp-how-portfolio-returns-can-be-created-out-of-thin-air)” by Richmond Quantitative Advisors (2021).

The main premise is a fair coin flip. If heads, you gain 50%. If tails, you lose 33.3%. They present the following equation

```
Average Arithmetic Return - Volatility Drag ≈ Geometric Average Return
```

where Volatility Drag = Volatility^2 ÷ 2.

They calculate the volatility as 42%. How was this deduced? Additionally, where could one find a resource that explains the mathematical derivation of both equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volatility is computed as the  standard deviation (SD) in finance.

- Average return (avg) is (150-66.6)/2 = 108.3
- SD: $\sqrt(0.5(150-avg)^2 + 0.5*((100-33.3)-avg)^2 = 41.65$

They just rounded it. Simplified, you can also just get the difference between max gain and average (150-avg) = 41.7

Or the difference between avg and min, (108.3 - 66.7) = 41.6